# Xamarin Forms project error NU1201

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hy everyone, my Visual Studio (2017) shows me an error in my Xamarin Forms project. I have developed an application (that uses some external packeges) and, from quite some time, i have an error that says:

> Error NU1201: Project "projectname".App.Android is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)/win-x86. Project "projectname".App.Android supports: monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)

I can't understand why i get this error, that seems to influence the installation of NuGet packages in the iOS project (it fails everytime).

The execution of the Android app doesn't have any problem, i can't try the iOS one at the moment, i am waiting for the key.

If someone had ever seen this error i'd like to have some help, thank you!

Comment: Did you use shared project for xamarin.forms? And could you please provide the codes in which, the error was thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by myself, somehow Visual Studio had added some kind of dependecy in the iOS project to the Android one, making it (obviously) incompatible. 
Visual Studio initialiy blocked me from removing it, i had to remove the dependency manually from the iOS ".csproj" and reload the solution.
Hope it helps if this happenes to someone else.

Comment: I just experienced the same issue, with the same solution. Very strange. However in my case VS allowed me to remove the dependency through the gui.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue because I tried to import a package designed for Android , not for iOS .